# Adding custom field type to Rating from Solspace

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

EE 2.9.2
Rating 3.3

I would like to add a custom field type, such as a Wygwam or RTE so that the comments field can have some formating controls. Just the basic ones, bold, italic etc.

Is it possible to add a custom field type to Rating?

Is it possible to add formatting controls to the textarea field?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "custom field type", you mean *EE Channel Entry Custom Fields*. Since ratings are not channel entries, this isn't possible, since Wygwam, RTE, etc are *Channel Entry* fields, not *Rating* fields.

However, you could add a WYSIWYG to a textarea field in your template manually by loading on of the WYSIWYG plugins available on the net. There are many available, including [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), and [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/). Make sure to respect the use license for these plugins as well.